yarn tsc --noEmit failed without output (SIGSEGV) [React Native Expo issue]
Unclear for what reason, when trying to commit to a React Native Expo project, I get the following error:
git commit -m "some commit"
✔ Preparing lint-staged...
⚠ Running tasks for staged files...
  ❯ lint-staged.config.js — 2 files
    ❯ **/*.(ts|tsx) — 2 files
      ✖ yarn tsc --noEmit [SIGSEGV]
    ❯ **/*.(ts|tsx|js) — 2 files
      ✖ yarn eslint --fix /screens/index.tsx /screens/detailsScreen.tsx 
      ◼ yarn prettier --write /screens/index.tsx /screens/detailsScreen.tsx
↓ Skipped because of errors from tasks.
✔ Reverting to original state because of errors...
✔ Cleaning up temporary files...

✖ yarn tsc --noEmit failed without output (SIGSEGV).

✖ yarn eslint --fix /screens/index.tsx /screens/detailsScreen.tsx failed without output (SIGSEGV).
husky - pre-commit script failed (code 1)

Everything was working perfectly just yesterday.
I haven’t changed anything in the project settings at all. Moreover, there are no errors in my code in the files mentioned above.
I tried clearing the Yarn cache, reinstalling the dependencies from package.json, restarting the IDE, and rebooting the PC
